# How do you migrate a SQL Membership database with encrypted passwords where the decryption key is autogenerated?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

have a server where the machine.config states the following:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1"/>
```

A decryption key was not specified, it was auto-generated. I'm moving this to a new server. How do I migrate the decryption and validation keys so that the database can be used on a new server?

Are these keys only used for Viewstate and Cookie Auth or are they used to generate the encrypted passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are autogenerated at runtime and can't be migrated.  It will only affect the auth tickets/Viewstate that are generated at runtime and not your stored passwords which should have their own salt stored separately from the hash in the DB.

Better to generate your own for the migration in case you need to add more servers in a farm.

Comment: So you are saying that the validation/decryption key specified above is NOT involved in generated/validating the passwords stored in the db?  So on new server I will specify those keys, but in the meantime, how would I migrate this db and still have the users be able to authenticate and validate those passwords?

Comment: Correct, if you are using the "Hashed" option for the passwordformat for the sql provider. On the new server I was just suggesting to manually generate the validation and encyrption keys in case you want to run it in on more than one machine.  There are some websites that will help generate these randomly.